# Can I specify extra param in app selector function while nesting component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, selector

**app.routing.module.ts file**

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {path: 'users/:id', component: UsersComponent},
];
```

**users.componenet.ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
```

**modal.component.ts file**

..............

```
   <div class="modal-body">
       <app-users></app-users>
</div>
```

...............

So the users component relies on being fed in an id (e.g users/1001), how how can I fed this into my app selector when trying to use it in modal window.

I have tried  <app-users/1001></app-users/1001> or <app-users/1002></app-users/1002> in it but this does not work and the modal window is blank even though these routes do work in my url to generate the specific data

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the component selector. To fulfill your requirement, you may have to define one more component which is almost same as your route component.

ChildUserComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-user',
  templateUrl: './child-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-users.component.css'],
})
export class ChildUsersComponent {
  @Input() userId: string;
}
```

Your users.componenet.ts

```
...
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  userId: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.userId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  }
}
```

Your users.componenet.html

```
<app-child-user [userId]="userId"></app-child-user>
```

Your modal.component.html

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <app-child-user [userId]="userId"></app-child-user>
</div>
```

Your modal.component.ts

```
...
userId: string;
...
```